# Zabbix server mysql connection issue

Tags: mysql, ssl, zabbix

I have installed Zabbix on centos6 system...But it have issue with mysql database connectivity....It starts with following information....

> 2196:20150225:120012.901 Cannot connect to the database. Exiting...
>   603:20150225:120013.077 Starting Zabbix Server. Zabbix 2.0.13
>   (revision 48919).    603:20150225:120013.079 ****** Enabled features
>   ******    603:20150225:120013.079 SNMP monitoring:           YES    603:20150225:120013.079 IPMI monitoring:           YES
>   603:20150225:120013.079 WEB monitoring:            YES
>   603:20150225:120013.079 Jabber notifications:      YES
>   603:20150225:120013.079 Ez Texting notifications:  YES
>   603:20150225:120013.079 ODBC:                      YES
>   603:20150225:120013.079 SSH2 support:              YES
>   603:20150225:120013.079 IPv6 support:              YES
>   603:20150225:120013.079 ******************************
>   603:20150225:120013.081 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix'
>   failed: [0] received invalid response to SSL negotiation: J

but fail with mysql connection issue...

32196:20150225:115544.414 Database is down. Reconnecting in 10 seconds.
 32196:20150225:115554.415 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [0] received invalid response to SSL negotiation: J

Mysql have_ssl setting is disabled in mysql database....

Comment: Check MySQL port settings: mysqld + zabbix-server - are the same?

Comment: ### Option: DBPort
#       Database port when not using local socket. Ignored for SQLite.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1024-65535
# Default (for MySQL):
 DBPort=3306

and same is being used by mysql

Comment: I just encountered this problem today. The problem is related to gnutls package version. Update gnutls package.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set DB items in `/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php` ?

```
$DB['TYPE']     = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']   = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']     = '0';
$DB['DATABASE'] = 'monitoring';
$DB['USER']     = 'monitor';
$DB['PASSWORD'] = 'zabbix';
```

Comment: No, this is just for zabbix-web.  phpian's error report could be zabbix-server's and in /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue at CentOS7 and zabbix20-* packages.

The reason of this issue was that /usr/sbin/zabbix_server_pgsql (apparently it is zabbix server for Postgres) was installed also, when I manually installed 'zabbix20-server'.  This zabbix_server_pgsql affects this issue;-(.  just installing zabbix20-server-mysql is the answer, or removing zabbx-server as follows is the workaround when zabbix_server_pgsql was installed:

1. remove zabbix20-server
2. and install only zabbix20-server-mysql again:
3. confirm that there is **NO** zabbix_server_pgsql under /usr/sbin.

[zabbix server cannot connect to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463638/zabbix-server-cannot-connect-to-database) gave me the hint.