# zabbix server cannot connect to database

Tags: mysql, zabbix

First, zabbix web gui can work, but zabbix server stutus is 'Not running'
[image]

It means mysql works correctly, because zabbix web can connect it.

Next, I checked zabbix server  /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log, here is the details:

> 14329:20160913:145134.438 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds
>   14329:20160913:145144.439 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix'
>   failed: [0] could not connect to server: Connection refused
>           Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 3306? received invalid response to SSL negotiation: R

Anyone who can help?

Comment: `mysql works correctly, because zabbix web can connect it` ... but how did you ascertain this?

Comment: If I add config by zabbix web, I can get the new records in mysql tables.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Both zabbix-mysql and zabbix-postgresql are installed. It seems there are some conflicts. Just remove zabbix-postgresql, it works.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the answer about zabbix-postgresql above
In my case zabbix-server-pgsql was installed along with zabbix-server-mysql.
After uninstalling zabbix-server-pgsql zabbix-server could be sucessfully started and connecting to MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my case I had started the Zabbix build with PostGreSQL first before using MySQL.

I then needed decided to go with MySQL so I could try out some of the additional DB features.

In this case, you could remove the specific Zabbix PGSQL instance which will not impact Postgres itself:

```
yum remove zabbix-server-pgsql
```

I would imagine if you moved to Postgres from MySQL the same would be true, but I have not yet tested this.

Thanks!

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.